# Angular2 dispatch DragEvent

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular, touch, dispatchevent

I need to dispatch and Create a new DragEvent

```
var dispatchedDragEvent = DOM.createEvent('DragEvent');                    
dispatchedDragEvent.initDragEvent('dragstart', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);                    
DOM.dispatchEvent(this.htmlElement, dispatchedDragEvent);
```

but I get the error initDragEvent is not a function, because `DOM.createEvent('DragEvent')` returns a object of Event and not 'DragEvent'

Can someone help me to create manually a `DragEvent` and dispatch it?

I need to convert a `TouchStart` to a `DragStart`.

Comment: I assume `DOM.createEvent('DravEvent')` was a typo (copy-paste error)

Comment: yes, it was a copy error but not the problem of my question =)

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done:

```js
@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
    onTouchStart(event) {
            let event1 = new DragEvent('dragstart');
            this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event1]);
        }
```

This might give a warning on compile, but works nonetheless.